# Backbone collection with CORS but no credentials

Tags: backbone.js, cors

I have an app made with backbone. When collections try to sync, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://someserver/menu.json. The value of 
the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be 
the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
Origin 'http://www.otherdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is 
controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

The collections just specify model and url, and have a simple parse.

I've try to override the sync method, as follows:

```
(function() {
  var proxiedSync = Backbone.sync;
  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    if (!options.crossDomain) {
      options.crossDomain = true;
    }
    if (!options.xhrFields) {
      options.xhrFields = {withCredentials:true};
    }
    return proxiedSync(method, model, options);
  };
})();
```

I run this function when app initialize. However, the error remains the same. I've tried different combinations (`withCredentials:false`, removing the line `withCredentials` etc) with no success.

The services are configured to serve '*'.

Is there a different way to tackle this problem?

Reconfiguring services or disabling browser security is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only execute if `xhrFields` is empty, maybe it is not.

Try something like

```
if (!options.xhrFields) {
  options.xhrFields = {};
}
options.xhrFields.withCredentials = false;
```

This will only solve the problem temporarily. In a real application you will need the credentials, and you should add a whitelist of domains in server to actually solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, the result is the same, both if I set true or false. Unfortunately, is not possible to re configure the server, and is set to *. I still don't get how to disable the withCredentials option.

Comment: @grahamo'donnel What version of jQuery are you using? this was added in 1.5 I believe. And when does this code run?

Comment: T J we're using jQuery v2.1.4. I've added the sync script in index.html, just after the script src tags.

Comment: Is this added before the request is triggered?

Comment: Yes, at the very beggining. In fact, I've added a console.log and appears four times (makes perfect sense since there are 4 collections on the home page)